# How can I make specific URL patterns open via a Chrome application shortcut?

Tags: google-chrome

I use Google Chrome *Application Shortcuts* for a quite a few internal tools hosted as internal websites.  Having them pinned as their own icon on the Windows 7 taskbar and *not* mixed in with the other browsers.

However, if I click on links in web pages, e-mails, etc. that are links into these tools, they open in the standard Chrome browser window, not the application shortcut window.

Is there a way to get Windows 7 or Google Chrome to target specific URL patterns to the application shortcut window instead of a new browser window?

Comment: I think this question is better suited in [su]

Comment: I was unaware of Super User, thanks! http://superuser.com/questions/456758/how-can-i-make-specific-url-patterns-open-via-a-chrome-application-shortcut